# change point style in EXCEL 2010 chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-2010

I need to change the point style of a chart in EXCEL 2010.

I have 10000 points, all are represented by diamonds that are overlaped each other in the chart.

It is very hard to see them clearly.

How to change them to a small point not diamonds ?

In EXCEL, available shapes are only diamonds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the marker style of the first series of the active chart:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection
    .MarkerStyle = 1  
    .MarkerSize = 5
End With
```

MarkerStyle 1 sets the series markers to circles and MarkerSize sets their size. Not sure if you have many series or all points on the same series. You will maybe have to loop over the series collection to change the style on all the series.